# How can I store records in a list request from an HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-web-api, data-binding, iterator, bind

How can I store records in a list from an HttpPost request that sends an object

I want to store each record that it processes again from the view

Take the _students object and send it to a list:
List  dbTempStudentList

To work locally with data and not depend on a database

```
[HttpPost]public ActionResult Create(Student _student)
{
return View("");
}
```

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string StudentLastName { get; set; }
    public string Creditbalance { get; set; }
    public string CurrentBalance { get; set; }
}
```

My View Create

```html
<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Student</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StudentID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StudentID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StudentID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StudentName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StudentName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StudentName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StudentLastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StudentLastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StudentLastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Creditbalance" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Creditbalance" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Creditbalance" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CurrentBalance" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CurrentBalance" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CurrentBalance" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a name attribute each input like asp-for attribute. For example first input must be like <input asp-for="StudentID" name="StudentID" class="form-control" />   After that, you can collect them into a list variable. Set the list into the session object. Check to using "HttpContext.Current.Session"

Comment: why? "Set the list into the session object." ?

Comment: @SerhatMERCAN. You do not add a `name` attribute - OP is using TagHelpers (the `asp-for`) which already adds the correct `name` attribute

Comment: Why do you not want to use a database? You need some kind of repository - a database, and external xml file, `Sesssion` etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(Student _student)
   {
          var list = (List<Student>)Session["studentList"];
          //this is for first time
          if(list==null||list.Count()==0) list = new List<Student>();

          list.Add(_student);
          Session["studentList"]=list;

          return View();
   }
```